# Does equality in $\Sigma_{(x : X)} x = x$ implies UIP?

Tags: coq, type-theory, equality

The short version:

Is this statement correct? If it is, is it provable in Coq?

```ml
Definition id_at { X : Set } ( x : X ) := x = x.
Definition id_at_eq_refl { X : Set } { x : X } ( p : x = x ) := existT id_at x p = existT id_at x eq_refl.
Proposition id_at_eq_refl_uip { X : Set } { x : X }
  : (forall (p : x = x), id_at_eq_refl p)
    -> (forall (p : x = x), p = eq_refl).
```

---

I recently stumbled upon the post [Dependent Pair Injectivity equivalent to K](https://coq.discourse.group/t/dependent-pair-injectivity-equivalent-to-k/1112/3) on Coq Discourse. The key idea to proof $DPI \implies K$ is that for a fixed `(x : X)` and any proof `(p : x = x)`, `existT (fun y => y = x) x p = existT (fun y => y = x) x eq_refl` always holds.

However, if we change the `(fun y => y = x)` to `(fun y => y = y)`, this equality does not hold. Later I found out that this is discussed in the HoTT book (Remark 1.12.1), and my understanding is that this is due to both end of the equality being fixed. This distinguishes the based loop space from the free path space, and in the based loop space one cannot just unwind the equality `p` and stay inside the space.

Another (maybe incorrect) observation of mine is that in the context of HoTT, if we choose $X = S^1$, moving around inside the based loop space $\Sigma_{(x : S^1)} x = x$ is same as changing the base point of the loop, and does not change the winding number of $p$. So $(x, p) = (x, \mathsf{refl})$ forces $p = \mathsf{refl}$.

So the question is can this generalize to other types, in contexts other than HoTT: For a given type $X$, Assuming for all proof $p : x = x$, the pair $(x, p)$ is equal to $(x, \mathsf{refl}_x)$ in the type $\Sigma_{(x : X) x = x}$, can we claim that x have unique identity proof, that is, $\forall (p : x = x), p = \mathsf{refl}_x$, **even without the injectivity of dependent pairs**?

Comment: HoTT book page numbers are unsable, please refer to the suitable section/lemma/theorem.

Comment: @andrej-bauer Sorry. I've updated the question to use the numbered remark.

Comment: By the way `id_at` is known as the **loop space** at $x$. Also, have you tried to prove the statement? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: @andrej-bauer I was mostly just trying to get an intuition of the correctness of the statement (in the settings of HoTT). I thought it would needs that $\Omega X$ splits, but later found out that the statement was precisely "if the loop space is path-connected, then the base space is simply connected", which should be true.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Indeed, it holds:

```
Definition id_at { X : Set } ( x : X ) := x = x.
Definition id_at_eq_refl { X : Set } { x : X } ( p : x = x ) := existT id_at x p = existT id_at x eq_refl.
Proposition id_at_eq_refl_uip { X : Set } { x : X }
  : (forall (p : x = x), id_at_eq_refl p)
    -> (forall (p : x = x), p = eq_refl).
Proof.
  intros H p.
  specialize (H p). unfold id_at_eq_refl in H.
  assert (projT2 (existT id_at x eq_refl) = @eq_refl _ (projT1 (existT id_at x eq_refl))) as Heqr by reflexivity.
  revert H Heqr.
  generalize (existT id_at x eq_refl) as k.
  intros k. intros <-. simpl. easy.
Qed.
```

The reason it works is interesting. We can generalize `existT id_at x eq_refl` as `k`, but still remember that its second component was `eq_refl`, because the type of `projT2 k` and `eq_refl` (on `projT1 k`) are the same (namely, `id_at`). Therefore, the first equality becomes usable (using an equality here usually means that you have to have the right-hand side be an unconstrained variable), so we can replace an `eq_refl` by `p` but still remember that it was `eq_refl` before, giving us `p = eq_refl`.

Comment: Can we use `H` to rewrite `Heqr` and avoid the `generalize` step? This is actually really interesting. Previously I tried to just use `f_equal` (or just prove that applying `projT2` to both end of the equality still yields a equality, then use `simpl`), but `projT2` is dependent, and the dependent version `f_equal_dep` doesn't not directly yield the required equality. That is what actually where the DPI comes into play in the DPI => K proof.

Comment: @LiuXiaoyi You can likely make the proof shorter. The one I originally found was, I made it longer to make it more didactic, and would be happy to see a more compact version.

Comment: @LiuXiaoyi also note that you can not avoid the `generalize` step, since that is required by how matches on `eq` necessarily work. You can merely make it implicit, i.e. have `rewrite` infer the right abstraction automatically by massaging the goal. You might be able to cleverly construct a proof term using `f_equal` and some tricky conversions.